# How to find the items of a given category with the max value in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I have a collection like this :

```
{_id: 1, value: 3, color: "white"}
{_id: 2, value: 5, color: "green"}
{_id: 3, value: 1, color: "white"}
{_id: 4, value: 2, color: "blue"}
{_id: 5, value: 4, color: "green"}
```

Is it possible to get the item with the highest value for each color ?

The expected output with our example would be :

```
{_id: 1, value: 3, color: "white"}
{_id: 2, value: 5, color: "green"}
{_id: 4, value: 2, color: "blue"}
```

The goal is to achieve this result in a single MongoDB request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB : Aggregation framework : Get last dated document per grouping ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23360551/mongodb-aggregation-framework-get-last-dated-document-per-grouping-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it through [`aggregation`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) as below

```
> db.collection.aggregate([
       {$sort: {'color': 1, value: -1}},
       {$group: {_id: '$color', value: {$first: '$value'}}}
 ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to group documents according to max value of color,you can perform aggregate operation utilizing [$max](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) operator

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
      $group: {
      _id:{color:"$color"},
      value:{$max:"$value"}
      }
    }

  ]
);
```

Comment: The goal was to get the whole items so this answer doesn't fit but thank you for the suggestion :)