# MongoDB aggregation for distinct values

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, distinct

I have 2 collections:

**user**

```
{
_id: 'user_id1',
username: 'user1',
}

{
_id: 'user_id2',
username: 'user2',
}

{
_id: 'user_id3',
username: 'user3',
}
```

***inbox***

```
{
_id: 'inbox_id1',
from: {_id: 'user_id1', username: 'user1'},
to: {_id: 'user_id2', username: 'user2'},
text: 'Hello there',
timestamp: new Date(),
}

{
_id: 'inbox_id2',
from: {_id: 'user_id1', username: 'user1'},
to: {_id: 'user_id2', username: 'user2'},
text: 'Trying again...',
timestamp: new Date(),
}

{
_id: 'inbox_id3',
from: {_id: 'user_id3', username: 'user3'},
to: {_id: 'user_id2', username: 'user2'},
text: 'You there?',
timestamp: new Date(),
}
```

Whenever a user goes into his inbox, I would like to show him the thread list, which should include a list of latest messages from each user. So basically I would like to get distinct documents (based on the `from._id` field), and only the latest document (based on `timestamp` field).

So my results for `user2` should include only 2 documents (`inbox_id2` and `inbox_id3`).

I know I need to use aggregation for it, but not sure how exactly.

Comment: What is your MongoDB server version?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve it based on a similar question: [MongoDB : Aggregation framework : Get last dated document per grouping ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23360551/mongodb-aggregation-framework-get-last-dated-document-per-grouping-id)

My solution looks like this:

```
db.inbox.aggregate([
    {$match : {'to.username': 'user2'}},
    {'$sort': {'from._id': 1, 'timestamp': -1}},
    {'$group': {
        '_id': '$from._id',
        'timestamp': {'$first': '$timestamp'},
        'text': {'$first': '$text'},
        'from': {'$first': '$from.username'},
    }},
]);
```

Comment: I ran this on my test data set and I am getting **oldest** message instead of **newest**  - please check your data set

Comment: @profesor79 it does. I first sort them based on timestamp and then extract the fields from the first document (which is the one with the most recent timestamp)