# MongoDb: grouping then sorting and taking last document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of documents. The documents each have a rev , quote and various other properties. I need to group by the quote number then select the single document in the group with latest rev. example 4 documents each with quote 12345 and rev A-D I need the "D" document and all the other docs with their latest revs sent to client.
I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23360551/mongodb-aggregation-framework-get-last-dated-document-per-grouping-id/%22HERE%22) but cant make it work for me.

query

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
{ "$group": {
   "_id": "$quote",
   "rev": { "$first":"$rev"}
}
])
```

collection

```
 {
  "_id" : ObjectId("58b6054c17c2cd53cf4176fe"),
  "rev" : "A",
  "quote" : "12345",
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("58b6085617c2cd53cf417710"),
  "rev" : "B",
  "quote" : "12345",
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("58b6da4617c2cd53cf417728"),
  "rev" : "C",
  "quote" : "12345",
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("58b6e5c317c2cd53cf417744"),
  "rev" : "D",
  "quote" : "12345",
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("58b6f44917c2cd53cf41776e"),
  "rev" : "A",
  "quote" : "54321",
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("58b6ffcb17c2cd53cf417788"),
  "rev" : "B",
  "quote" : "54321",
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the sort like the other answer mentioned ? Something like `db.myCollection.aggregate([{"$sort":{"quote":1, "rev":1 }},
{ "$group": {
   "_id": "$quote",
   "rev": { "$last":"$rev"}
}
])`

Comment: @Veeram that did return data but it was only the _id and rev property. How do I get the entire document?

Comment: Try `db.myCollection.aggregate([{"$sort":{"quote":1, "rev":1 }}, { "$group": { "_id": "$quote", "data": { "$last":"$$ROOT"} } ])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Veeram for this solution.

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([{"$sort":{"quote":1, "rev":1 }}, { "$group": { "_id": "$quote", "data": { "$last":"$$ROOT"} } ])
```